# After connect and script execution back to previous sql plus session possible?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

```
sqlplus dba/foo@bar @test.sql;
```

with `test.sql`:

```
SELECT user FROM dual;
USER
-------
dba

CONNECT foo/foo@bar;
SELECT user FROM dual;
USER
-------
foo

DISCONNECT; -- My problem: Doesn't go back to dba session.

SELECT user FROM dual;
SP2-0640: Not connected
```

How can I go back to previous SQL Plus session (here `dba`) without open a new SQL Plus session? **But**: I don't have the login credentials for `dba` available within script `test.sql` because the initial SQL Plus session for `dba` is created outside in a shell script!

SQL Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> DISCONNECT; -- My problem: Doesn't go back to dba session.
> ```

Of course; you said you want to *disconnect*, not to *connect as someone else*. Instead of that, use

```
connect dba/foo@bar
```

Comment: I don't have the login credentials for `dba` available within `test.sql`.

Comment: What prevents you to put it in there?